# How to get csrf-token from meta tag

Tags: python-3.x

```
import requests
import re
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with requests.Session() as s:
        login_session = s.get('https://prod.facilgo.com/users/sign_in')
        data = login_session.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
        print(soup)
        csrf_token = soup.find("meta", name="csrf-token")
        print(csrf_token["content"])
```

Is there any solution to get the csrf token from the meta tag using beautiful soup . I am getting error: TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary to provide name attribute to beautiful soup:

```
import requests
import re
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with requests.Session() as s:
        login_session = s.get('https://prod.facilgo.com/users/sign_in')
        data = login_session.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
        print(soup)
        csrf_token = soup.find("meta", {"name": "csrf-token"})
        print(csrf_token["content"])
```